# Which hashing algorithm is used by PHP session.hash_function mixed as default

Tags: php, initialization

Which hashing algorithm is used by PHP  session.hash_function as default?
The following page says that default is md5 "0":
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function
However the hash algo page shows code "0" to be md2.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php

If code "0" on php.ini really corresponds to md5 then what are the codes for other hash algorithms for php.ini ? For example what is the code for sha512?

Answer (score 7):

If you run `print_r(hash_algos());` the follwing array is a more reliable way find which settings is for which algorithm, as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function)

> A complete list of supported algorithms can be obtained with the hash_algos() function.

I ran it with the PHP 7.0.5

```
Array
(
    [0] => md2
    [1] => md4
    [2] => md5
    [3] => sha1
    [4] => sha224
    [5] => sha256
    [6] => sha384
    [7] => sha512
    [8] => ripemd128
    [9] => ripemd160
    [10] => ripemd256
    [11] => ripemd320
    [12] => whirlpool
    [13] => tiger128,3
    [14] => tiger160,3
    [15] => tiger192,3
    [16] => tiger128,4
    [17] => tiger160,4
    [18] => tiger192,4
    [19] => snefru
    [20] => snefru256
    [21] => gost
    [22] => gost-crypto
    [23] => adler32
    [24] => crc32
    [25] => crc32b
    [26] => fnv132
    [27] => fnv1a32
    [28] => fnv164
    [29] => fnv1a64
    [30] => joaat
    [31] => haval128,3
    [32] => haval160,3
    [33] => haval192,3
    [34] => haval224,3
    [35] => haval256,3
    [36] => haval128,4
    [37] => haval160,4
    [38] => haval192,4
    [39] => haval224,4
    [40] => haval256,4
    [41] => haval128,5
    [42] => haval160,5
    [43] => haval192,5
    [44] => haval224,5
    [45] => haval256,5
)
```

**More details:**

The function `hash_algos` returns an array of string. The indexes of the array does not indicate the setting  for the ini file. You should use the string, i. e. "sha512" for the ini setting, like `session.hash_function = sha512`.

As it is written in the docs, to specify a string value is possible since PHP 5.3

> Since PHP 5.3.0 it is also possible to specify any of the algorithms provided by the hash extension (if it is available), like *sha512* or *whirlpool*.

**To answer your two questions:**

1. What is the default value?

The default value is "0" - as you can see in the [offical PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L878) on Github

2. What other values, despite "0" and "1" are allowed respectively documented?

Well, that's a bit harder to explain, but I try. According to the C implementation for this value, that you can find [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L776). According to the [checks inside this function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L788) there seem to only be [*0*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L795) or [*1*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L802) or [*other*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L812) values. The *other* values seems to be those from the hash_algos() array.

3. Why is 0=MD5 and 1=SHA1? (you may ask)
   Because of this [`enum`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L262) in C

   enum {
           PS_HASH_FUNC_MD5,
           PS_HASH_FUNC_SHA1,
           PS_HASH_FUNC_OTHER
       };

Frankly speeking you can put (kind of array-)indexes before which then results in

```
0 => PS_HASH_FUNC_MD5,
1 => PS_HASH_FUNC_SHA1,
... PS_HASH_FUNC_OTHER
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it doesn't answer the question. The php.ini says code "0" is md5 yet all versions of php show code 0 to be md2 when using print_r(hash_algos());. So looks like php.ini uses different codes than hash algo codes. If so then what are the codes for php.ini.

Comment: @Jimski updated my answer with more details. Hopefully that makes things clearer.

Comment: @Jimski Edited again, hope it answers your question

Comment: @Jimski Thanks a lot! Good we came to the same conclusion, even if it took some time ;)

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it explains everything very well. I was just looking at sessions.c and came to the same conclusion. Thank you.

Comment: "Note: This setting was introduced in PHP 5. Removed in PHP 7.1.0. "